# compatibility issue spring-beans,hibernate-core,spring-boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

there are lot of questions regarding compatibility already.I think this still waste lots of time of developer even after spring-boot.Unfortunately today i got trapped as i am also new in spring boot .Here is my issue:
I was using spring-boot's 1.4.2.RELEASE which has hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar
Whose org.hibernate.Session interface has following signature:

```
public interface Session extends SharedSessionContract, java.io.Closeable {...
```

So i cannot use session.getCriteriaBuilder() method.
After some investigation i found that this will work with hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar as it has this signature:

```
public interface Session extends SharedSessionContract, EntityManager, HibernateEntityManager, AutoCloseable...
```

Obviously i will need upgraded vesrion of hibernate and hence spring-boot.I choose 2.0.0.RELEASE, But i am not able to solve this exception since long:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.marketsforcaster.main.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:37)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 13 more
```

Adding pic for more clarity,(one thing i can notice in pic that jar icon is different than other jar icon may be it will help to identify problem soon) after expanding the jar i can see the class .Please help as i am stuck.

[image]
[image]

I tried following so that please exclude these in your answer:
1.Using previous version of spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, can't use as previous version don't have  hibernate-core-5.2.11.Final.jar.
2.Explicitly giving hibernate-version in pom as 5.2.11.Final, it may create issue with other jars and will fail the sole purpose of using the spring-boot in itself.

Comment: I would guess that your `spring-bean-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar` file is corrupted. Try deleting it and rebuilding your application.

Comment: after deleting it worked .Thanks .